# Migrate data from Mysql to MongoDB using pymongo

Tags: python, mysql, json, mongodb, pymongo

I am creating a script Python (using pymongo) to migrate my data from Mysql to MongoDB (5 million of rows), but I am having some problems.
My idea is to retrieve the data from Mysql using SQL and create a JSON structure to insert in MongoDB, but the data types are giving a problem and I don't know how to solve it.

So, I created a simple example to show the problem.

1. In Mysql, I created a table and insert one row. After that, I retrived this one using SQL into MySQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees (
  id1 int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nome1 varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  nick1 varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  age1 int(5) NOT NULL,
  date1 date DEFAULT NULL,
  time1 time DEFAULT NULL,
  datetime1 datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id1)
) ENGINE=MyISAM CHARSET=latin1;
```

```sql
INSERT INTO employees (id1, nome1, nick1, age1, date1, time1, datetime1) 
VALUES (1, 'MARIA SILVA', null, 35, '2020-12-23', '12:30:22', '2020-07-02 03:17:40');
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM employees;
+-----+-------------+-------+------+------------+----------+---------------------+
| id1 | nome1       | nick1 | age1 | date1      | time1    | datetime1           |
+-----+-------------+-------+------+------------+----------+---------------------+
|   1 | MARIA SILVA | NULL  |   35 | 2020-12-23 | 12:30:22 | 2020-07-02 03:17:40 |
+-----+-------------+-------+------+------------+----------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

2. So far everything ok. Let's go to Python using pymongo:

```python
### Python Script - Retrieving data from Mysql
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pprint import pprint
import mysql.connector
import datetime

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="user",
  password="password",
  database="test"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM employees")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
for x in myresult:
    print(x)
```

The result is below. Completly diferent format if compared to Mysql return:

```
(1, 'MARIA SILVA', None, 35, datetime.date(2020, 12, 23), datetime.timedelta(seconds=45022), datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 2, 3, 17, 40))
```

3. That is ok, but now I need to use this one to create a JSON item and insert into MongoDB

```python
### Python Script - Retrieving data from Mysql and creating JSON item:
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pprint import pprint
import mysql.connector
import datetime

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
   host="localhost",
   user="user",
   password="password",
   database="test"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
for x in myresult:
   item = { 
      "_id" : int(x[0]), 
      "id1" : int(x[0]), 
      "name1" : x[1], 
      "nick1" : x[2], 
      "age1" : x[3], 
      "date1" : x[4], 
      "time1" : x[5], 
      "datetime1" : x[6] 
   }
pprint(item)
```

The result is JSON below:

```json
{
   '_id': 1,
   'id1': 1, 
   'name1': 'MARIA SILVA',
   'nick1': None,
   'age1': 35,
   'date1': datetime.date(2020, 12, 23),
   'time1': datetime.timedelta(seconds=45022),
   'datetime1': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 2, 3, 17, 40)
 }
```

That is the problem. When I try to insert this one into MongoDB, I get errors because MongoDB doesn't recognize these:

```json
'nick1': None #(MongoDB uses null instead of None but I don't know how to fix it)
'date1': datetime.date(2020, 12, 23) #(I don't know how to do)
'time1': datetime.timedelta(seconds=45022), #(I don't know how to do)
'datetime1': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 2, 3, 17, 40) #(I don't know how to do)
```

So, can someone help me in order to fix that bad JSON in a correct JSON to insert into MongoDB?

Finally, this is the code to insert the item into MongoDB:

```python
### Python Script (continuing)- Inserting JSON item:
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.test
col = db.employees
item_id = col.insert_one(item).inserted_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Studio 3T tool for MongoDB (limited to 1000 lines, I got this acceptable JSON for MongoDB:

```json
{ 
    "_id" : NumberInt(1), 
    "id1" : NumberInt(1), 
    "name1" : "MARIA SILVA", 
    "nick1" : null, 
    "age1" : NumberInt(35),
    "date1" : ISODate("2020-12-23T03:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "time1" : "12:30:22", 
    "datetime1" : ISODate("2020-07-02T03:17:40.000+0000")
}
```

But how can I fix that bad JSON to look like this one?

Comment: hey @Adriano, glad to learn your python script for migration, can we connect i had queries if there is more than 3 tables, then how we can we migrate effeciently